# Pythonic split list into n random chunks of roughly equal size

Tags: python

As part of my implementation of cross-validation, I find myself needing to split a list into chunks of roughly equal size.

```
import random

def chunk(xs, n):
    ys = list(xs)
    random.shuffle(ys)
    ylen = len(ys)
    size = int(ylen / n)
    chunks = [ys[0+size*i : size*(i+1)] for i in xrange(n)]
    leftover = ylen - size*n
    edge = size*n
    for i in xrange(leftover):
            chunks[i%n].append(ys[edge+i])
    return chunks
```

This works as intended

```
>>> chunk(range(10), 3)
[[4, 1, 2, 7], [5, 3, 6], [9, 8, 0]]
```

But it seems rather long and boring. Is there a library function that could perform this operation? Are there pythonic improvements that can be made to my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import random

def chunk(xs, n):
    ys = list(xs)
```

Copies of lists are usually taken using `xs[:]`

```
    random.shuffle(ys)
    ylen = len(ys)
```

I don't think storing the length in a variable actually helps your code much

```
    size = int(ylen / n)
```

Use `size = ylen // n` // is the integer division operator

```
    chunks = [ys[0+size*i : size*(i+1)] for i in xrange(n)]
```

Why the `0+`?

```
    leftover = ylen - size*n
```

Actually, you can find size and leftover using `size, leftover = divmod(ylen, n)`

```
    edge = size*n
    for i in xrange(leftover):
            chunks[i%n].append(ys[edge+i])
```

You can't have `len(leftovers) >= n`. So you can do:

```
   for chunk, value in zip(chunks, leftover):
       chunk.append(value)


    return chunks
```

Some more improvement could be had if you used numpy. If this is part of a number crunching code you should look into it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a library function that could perform this operation?

No.

> Are there pythonic improvements that can be made to my code?

A few.

Sorry it seems boring, but there's not much better you can do.

The biggest change might be to make this into a generator function, which may be a tiny bit neater.

```
def chunk(xs, n):
    ys = list(xs)
    random.shuffle(ys)
    size = len(ys) // n
    leftovers= ys[size*n:]
    for c in xrange(n):
        if leftovers:
           extra= [ leftovers.pop() ] 
        else:
           extra= []
        yield ys[c*size:(c+1)*size] + extra
```

The use case changes, slightly, depending on what you're doing

```
chunk_list= list( chunk(range(10),3) )
```

The `if` statement can be removed, also, since it's really two generators.  But that's being really fussy about performance.

```
def chunk(xs, n):
    ys = list(xs)
    random.shuffle(ys)
    size = len(ys) // n
    leftovers= ys[size*n:]
    for c, xtra in enumerate(leftovers):
        yield ys[c*size:(c+1)*size] + [ xtra ]
    for c in xrange(c+1,n):
        yield ys[c*size:(c+1)*size]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a generator.  You could then simplify the logic.

```
def chunk(xs, n):
    ys = list(xs)
    random.shuffle(ys)
    chunk_length = len(ys) // n
    needs_extra = len(ys) % n
    start = 0
    for i in xrange(n):
        if i < needs_extra:
            end = start + chunk_length + 1
        else:
            end = start + chunk_length
        yield ys[start:end]
        start = end
```